# How to construct a particular graph similar to the line graph

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, igraph

Suppose that `G` is a directed graph object in python-igraph (ver. 0.7). I want to create the following graph `L` related to `G`:

1. The nodes of `L` correspond to edges of `G`
2. Every node `x` of `L` **has an attribute** `(i,j)` if `x` corresponds to the edge  `i--->j`of `G`. Here by simplicity we denote `x` as `x.(i,j)`
3. There is an edge in  `L`, `x.(i,j)--->y.(k,l)` if and only if `j=k` and `i!=l`.

The adjacency matrix of `L` is called the Hashimoto matrix of `G`.

A **wrong** way to create such `L` is the following: First we put `L=G.linegraph()` and then we delete the mutual edges from `L`. The problem with this approach is that we  haven't the attributes related to the vertices of `L`.

Do you have any idea/hint for the construction of `L`?

Answer (score 0):

Please correct me if I am wrong, but if I understand it correctly then the only problem with the output of `L = g.linegraph()` is that the attributes are not attached to the vertices of `L`. Is that correct? If so, they are easy to add because vertex *i* in the line graph is the same as edge *i* in the original graph, so you can do this:

```
L.vs["original_edge"] = G.get_edgelist()
```